# Tensorflow Keras GPU uses

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.5

I'm trying to make tensorflow and keras go on GPU in my code but I'm having problem that the uses are partially (the CPU is still used by both)

- **Force keras to GPU**
  to force keras to GPU I added this code before keras importation, I just force it to the first GPU, I didn't configure how to run on multiple GPU (when I tried 
  `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1,2,3"` an error occurred when running the project, I have 4 GPU)

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"  
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
```

- **Force tensorflow to GPU**

for tensorflow I installed tensorflow-gpu then i run this code as mentioned in the tensorflow official page
[tensorflow official](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

        if gpus:
            # Restrict TensorFlow to only use the first GPU
            try:
                tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')
                logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
                logger.info(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPU")
            except RuntimeError as e:
                # Visible devices must be set before GPUs have been initialized
                logger.error("Error inn workig on GPU %s " % e)
```

the problem persist and the use of the GPU is not passing 15% and the cpu is at 40% of uses.

[tensorflow is runing  GPU  15%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE2O1.png)

[tensorflow is runing  CPU 40%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W9o6.png)

Comment: "an error occurred" - please specify. The error usually contains what's wrong and general directions on how to solve it. It's not there just to bother users.

Comment: have you installed tensorflow-gpu?2.0 or less?keras?2.3.0 or less?some information are useful for a better helping

Comment: tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.12.0
Keras==2.2.4
for the error i will try to make a capture with it.

Comment: do you use anaconda to install the environments?

Comment: no i'm not using anaconda

Comment: 15% GPU usage does not mean that it is not using the GPU, what model are you training? Have you considered that you are just not putting enough computational load to fill a GPU?

Comment: We use VGG16 model, but is that normal that the cpu is running at 40% when the GPU is 15%